# CV question about hspace

Tags: tables, moderncv, cv, tabulary

I use this code for my CV

```
\section{Skills}

\cvitem{Languages}{
English \hspace{6.52cm} Intermediate}

\cvitem{Programming}{
VBA for Excel, MATLAB, Python, C++ \hspace{1.11cm} Basic
\newline
\LaTeX , C, R, Office, Bloomberg \hspace{2.68cm} Intermediate}
```

How Can I do it without hspace?
Thx to all.

The result is this

[image]

Comment: use tabbing environment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `\cvitemwithcomment` command as shown in the following example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{moderncv}
\name{firstname}{lastname}

\moderncvstyle{casual}
\moderncvcolor{blue}

\begin{document}
\makecvtitle
\section{Skills}

\cvitemwithcomment{Languages}{English}{Intermediate}
\cvitemwithcomment{Programming}{VBA for Excel, MATLAB, Python, C++ }{Basic}
\cvitemwithcomment{}{\LaTeX , C, R, Office, Bloomberg }{Intermediate}

\end{document}
```